# spacy is not getting installed

Tags: python, spacy

When I install **spacy** with pip it download a bunch of files but at the end this error comes and spacy is not getting installed although setuptools is installed.

Command `"/usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-jugolqe4/murmurhash/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-fwk4l5m8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-jugolqe4/murmurhash/`

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed on your system?

Comment: No C is not installed on my system

Comment: Try installing some kind of C compiler (homebrew, xcode) and then installing spacy again.

Comment: I learned that homebrew and xcode are for mac I am currently on ubuntu 16.04. I had installed spacy before and then it worked fine without c compiler. Then why would it require c compiler now

Answer (score 1):

A lot of parts of spaCy are written in Cython for improved performance. Thus, in order to use spaCy library you need a C compiler to compile Cython code.

You could try running the following commands in your terminal and then retry installing spacy.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
gcc -v
make -v
```